# How can I pass a file from a python program to a perl script and then reopen it in python?

Tags: python, bash, perl, subprocess

I have a python program that opens and manipulates a file. It takes a file with a single fasta entry (ex1) and splits it into a mulit-fasta file (ex2).

ex1:

```
>genome_fasta
ATCG.... (thousands of chars)
```

ex 2:

```
>genome_split_1
ATCG.... (300 chars)
>genome_split_2
GCTT.... (300 chars)
>genome_split_3
ATGG....(300 chars, etc.)
```

That is working fine. But now I want to get the penta-nucleotide frequencies for each one of these fasta entries. I have a perl script that does this nicely and formats the output how I want it.

How can I pass my file (ex2) to this perl script, run it and get my output file, then pass the file back into my python script for further manipulation?

I have tried to understand the subprocess module because that seems like the easiest idea (i.e. just run a subprocess on the terminal that runs the ./perl_script.pl), but can't figure it out.

Comment: is the perl script writing to the file?

Comment: No, it is not directly writing to the file I pass into the perl script. Perl is taking a file as input (the file made from my python script) and creating a new file based on that information. This new file is what I would like to put back into my python script for further manipulation

Comment: so you are passing a filename or the content? Also would it not be easier do all the work in one or the other instead of both?

Comment: I only know how to code in python, but I have a handy script given to me by my adviser that is written in perl. What I figured I could do was the following: Start my python script - it creates a file in the directory where I ran it. I then run the perl script by writing a child process to the command line (./my_perl.pl file_created_from_python.txt out_perl_file.txt). The perl script takes created_from_python.txt and makes a new file called out_perl_file.txt. Then I want the python program (still running) to read in the out_perl_file.txt for further manipulation.

Comment: I am not familiar with perl but you would just want to make sure the data was written to the file before you opened it in perl and the same when you open it again in python to read the updated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popen method of the subprocess module.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['perl', 'myscript.perl'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
```

output variable is then your text.

Comment: The OP wants to pass a file to perl  then reopen it in python so I think there is going to be a bit more involved than this

Comment: @Padraic he can pass a string as an argument or the filepath as an argument. Then his call will wait until its done. He can then check if the error code is 0 and go further. That way he doesn't need to check async if the perl program is done. If I understand correctly.

Comment: using `check_call` or `check_output` would be much simpler depending on what the perl script is doing,  if the OP is writing to the file in both python and perl then it may also get more complicated.